# Does higher variance usually mean lower probability density?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function

Does higher variance usually mean lower probability density? Despite the type of distribution. Thank you.

Update：

Sorry for confusion. Please allow me to clarify. If I sample the same number of data points from two distributions of the same type, but one distribution with a lower variance and another one with a higher variance, would the former sample have higher likelihood?

An example with Gaussian distributions:

1. Sample $\mathbf{X_1}$ from $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$
2. Sample $\mathbf{X_2}$ from $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$, where $\sigma_1 < \sigma_2$,

is it true that $P(\mathbf{X_1}; N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)) < P(\mathbf{X_2}; N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2))$?

Comment: Hi: the density integrates to 1 regardless of the distribution so it's not clear what you mean by lower ?

Comment: in general, the answer to your question is no, as shown by the counterexample provided by @ThomasLumley.

Comment: What do you mean by "distributions of the same type"?

Comment: @Dave Hey, for example, two Gaussian distributions $N(\mu_1 , \sigma_{1}^{2})$ and $N(\mu_2 , \sigma_{2}^{2})$.

Comment: That's one example.  How about two Gamma distributions?  Or two Student $t$ distributions?  It *appears* what you're trying to ask concerns *scale* families of distributions, where changing the scale must change the density uniformly so that it continues to integrate to unity, as every density must.  But that's only a guess.

Comment: Re the edited question: the answer is a very resounding *no,* because the laws of chance imply that sometimes a sample from one distribution will look like it's a sample from a very different distribution (having the same support).  There aren't any guarantees: that's why the sample is called *random.*

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much for your answer. Re "sometimes a sample from one distribution will look like it's a sample from a very different distribution", I guess this is possible only if the sample size is small? What if with large sample size, is the statement in the edited question true? Thank you!

Comment: It's possible for a sample of *any* size.  The only difference is that the probability your sample looks very different from its generating distribution becomes smaller as the sample size increases.  This is one of the "laws of large numbers."

Comment: The "expected density" corresponding to a single value sampled from a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$  distribution is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}\sigma}$ so (as you might expect) scales inversely to the standard deviation.

Comment: This tells you nothing about likelihood, which is a relative or ratio concept only proportional to density; looking at different samples from different distributions does not really give anything to compare.  If I sample heights in centimetres from a $N(175, 10^2)$ distribution seeing the values $162, 177, 183$, I cannot say this is "less likely" than sampling heights in metres from a $N(1.75, 0.10^2)$ distribution seeing $1.62, 1.77, 1.83$ - they are clearly equally likely in any meaningful sense as they are exactly the same measurements but on a different scale.

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much Henry, you answered my question with good examples.

Answer (score 17):

Up to a point. Because the density integrates to 1, the typical value of the density will be higher if the distribution has a lower variance and lower if it has a higher variance.  For example, the maximum density of a Normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$ is $1/(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$, which gets lower as $\sigma$ gets higher. On the other hand, because the distribution with larger variance is more spread out, it has higher density out in the tails. For example, here are two Normal distributions, with variance 1 and 4.

[image]

The distribution with variance 1 has higher density in the middle, but lower density at the edges.

However, if you have two distributions with different shapes, it's harder to make generalisations.

Comment: Thank you so much. What if I sample the same number of data points from the two distributions? Would the samples from the distribution with lower variance have a higher likelihood?

Comment: Note that the OP has specified different means, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, though perhaps that happened after you had posted your answer.

Comment: Your question in the comment @TaroYamPotato is about $$\mathbb E_{X \sim p}[ \log p(X)] = \int p(x) \log p(x) \mathrm d x,$$ for a distribution with density $p$. This is known as the negative of the _differential entropy_ and, for Gaussians, would indeed be lower if the variance is lower; the formula for Gaussians is $\frac12 + \frac12 \ln(2 \pi) + \ln \sigma$.

Answer (score 2):

Standard deviation and probability density are exactly inversely correlated in one common and important case: scaled distributions, i.e. the distributions of $a\cdot X$ for different $a$ and same random variable $X$. Thomas' answer has a great example of this.

In the more general case, there does not have to be any relation. For example, take the mixture of two Gaussians at $+a$ and $-a$, with stdev $\sigma$ each. As long as $a \gg \sigma$ (so the Gaussians don't overlap), the maximum density is $1/(2\sqrt{2\pi}\, \sigma)$ and thus independent of $a$, while the variance $a^2 + \sigma^2$ depends strongly on $a$.

Edit: If we now increase $a$ while decreasing $\sigma$, variance and peak density both increase simultaneously, making it a true counterexample.

Comment: The effect is slight in the second case, but the maximum density is lower the farther apart the Gaussians are - there is no distance at which the Gaussians don't overlap. The effect can be made arbitrarily small, but not eliminated. This is an example of association between variance and peak density, not a counterexample.

Comment: It's simpler to mix two uniform distributions than two Gaussian distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Response to updated question: *If I sample 100 data points from two distributions of the same type, but one with a lower variance and one with a higher variance, would the former one have higher likelihood?*

The likelihood $L(\theta|X)$ depends on both the parameter $\theta$ and the random sample $X$, so it's hard to know what is meant by a "higher likelihood."  If

- you have *one* sample $X$ taken from *one* distribution $P$, and
- all parameters of $P$ are known save the variance $\sigma^2$, and
- you know that $\sigma^2\in\{\sigma^2_1,\sigma^2_2\}$, where $\sigma^2_1<\sigma^2_2$,

then the likelihood ratio $\frac{L(\sigma^2_1|X)}{L(\sigma^2_2|X)}\equiv \prod_{i=1}^{100} \frac{ p(x_i|\sigma^2_1)}{ p(x_i|\sigma^2_2)}$ reflects the evidence in favor of either of the two possible values of $\sigma^2$.  A very high dispersion of $X$ will result in $L(\sigma^2_1|X)<L(\sigma^2_2|X)$, but this is a higher likelihood only in the sense that $\sigma_2^2$ is more likely than $\sigma_1^2$  to be the true value of $\sigma^2$.  If the dispersion of $X$ is very low, of course, you will have $L(\sigma^2_1|X)>L(\sigma^2_2|X)$.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers. If we interpret the question as about the *expected* density (or likelihood) of the sample, then the answer is affirmative. If $X$ is a random variable with the density function $f$, then the expected density at the observation $X$ is
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} 
   \E f(X) = \int f(x)^2 \; dx
$$ and this will be smaller if the variance is larger. Specifically, for a scale family with $f_\sigma(x) = \frac1\sigma f(\frac{x}{\sigma})$ we find that
$$ \E f_\sigma(X) = \int f_\sigma(x)^2 \; dx = \frac1\sigma \int f(x)^2\; dx
$$  so it scales with the standard deviation. See also [Does the integral of the probability density function squared mean something?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314466/does-the-integral-of-the-probability-density-function-squared-mean-something/623642#623642)

If we instead of using the density itself, focuses on the log density, as we often do when using the density as a likelihood function, what we get is
$$ \int \log(f(x)) \cdot f(x)\; dx$$
which is the (negative of) *differential entropy*. This scales with variance as shown in [How does entropy depend on location and scale?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415435/how-does-entropy-depend-on-location-and-scale)

Answer (score 0):

"Probability density" is not a single number that can be lower or higher. It's a function $p(x)$ of $x$. Usually it also depends on some additional parameters $q_i$. For example, in the normal distribution, we have $q_1 = \mu$ and $q_2 = \sigma$.

To change variance, you would change these parameters. You could also change the function itself, if you hadn't said "same distribution". When you change those parameters, you will also alter $p(x)$, which may become higher or lower depending on the exact function. So no, it is not true that higher variance will always reduce probability density. For example, for a normal distribution, extreme values will have higher density.

To give a specific counter example, let's talk about the probability of getting $2 < x < 3$:

- With a normal distribution $N(0, 1)$, $p(x > 2) = 0.023$ and $p(x > 3) = 0.001$ therefore $p(2 < x < 3) = 0.022$.
- With a normal distribution $N(0, 4)$, $p(x > 2) = 0.158$ and $p(x > 3) = 0.067$ therefore $p(2 < x < 3) = 0.091$

In this case, the probability density between 2 and 3 has *increased* when variance went from 1 to 4.

I had to change your example a little, because this is trivial:

> is it true that $P(\mathbf{X_1}; N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)) < P(\mathbf{X_2}; N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2))$?

You've left too many independent variables, so I can say $X_1 = \mu_1$ and $X_2 = \mu_2 + 10 \sigma_2$ and then it is false, or vice versa and it is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering the likelihood of the samples from such two distributions. In your example, if we sample many data points from $N(0,1)$ and from N(0,4), respectively, the two samples would be different. I was wondering the likelihoods of the two samples given the distribution where they were sampled.

Comment: @TaroYamPotato The likelihood you describe is exactly what my calculations show. If you sampled 1000 points from either distribution, about 22 would be between 2 and 3 for the first distribution, and about 91 for the second.

Answer (score -1):

just take 10 points : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 (discrete samples)
the mean is: 5.5 and you may take variance to be approx. = 3
this standardizes the data to -1.5,-1.167,-0.83,-0.5,-0.1667,0.1667,0.5,0.833,1.1667,1.5

*(now imagine the same thing for a continuous domain)*
so if you observe the plot, the PDF will be a curve closer to 1 at E(X) which is well, the most probable value of X and that after standardization is 0. So, the curve is denser around X=0 and not so dense as you move to sides which is why you observe a bell curve post standardization.
but if you look at the original data; the variance = 3(approx.) > 1. If the data were continuous; the mean being 5.5 would imply that the curve peaks at X=5.5(well, not exactly X=5.5 because then f(x) = 0, lets say in an interval epsilon around 5.5) yes; however the variance being larger means the next value is at a greater distance. Notice how 2-1 = 1, 3-2 = 1 but; -0.83-(-1.167) = 0.337 < 1. think of balls scattered in a playground vs. gathered in one place. the density is higher in that one place but negligent in other parts of the playground. in the first case, the density is well, not that high except at some place where you have 2 balls or something.

this also helps answer the question: why would you want to collect them all in one place? well because then it's easier to find.

Comment: I lost you at "observe the plot:" *what* plot, exactly?  What is the PDF of "just ... 10 points"?  If by "E(X)" you mean (as is conventional) the expectation, then it's invalid to characterize it as "the most probable value," which would be a *mode.*  (The same error occurs in characterizing the sample mean as where a curve "peaks.") A "larger" variance (larger than what?) says little or nothing about *gaps* in the data, such as "the next value." The problems in this post go on and on, but if you would like to fix it, consider starting with these issues.