# Why does the Shannon index take the log of number and then multiply the number by that log?

Tags: logistic, entropy, diversity

I am looking to Shannon index formula in diversity. Part of the formula I am having trouble following. For example, 50 foxes at site 1, 60 foxes site 2 and 100 foxes site 3.  Across all sites there are 210 foxes.

50 / 210 = 0.23809. Then get that log (0.23809)

60/ 210 = 0.28571. Log (0.28571)

100/210 = 0.47619. Log (0.47619)

But the formula goes on to multiply them together: $p\cdot \log(p)$, viz., $0.23809\times \log(0.23809)$, and so on for the others. It adds up the total for each together. Using the formula as context, I want to know what $p\cdot \log(p)$ does in statistics? That is, why multiply the number, e.g., 0.23809 by the log of the number?  It’s not the formula that’s the problem - it’s multiplying the the number by its log. Is that a usual thing in logs? What is the aim / reason of it? IF I were to multiply it by 100/1 I would get the proposition. But why multiply a number by the log of the same number?

Comment: We need more context.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to describe the (negative of the) *entropy* of a discrete distribution.  See the [Wikipedia article on diversity indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index), for instance.

Comment: Yes that’s it, multiple pi x log(pi)

Comment: You are asking why entropy is defined the way it is.  See for for one possible explanation:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66186/statistical-interpretation-of-maximum-entropy-distribution/245198#245198

Comment: Shannon's paper on the topic is very readable. I'd recommend starting there. http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Your question describes Shannon entropy. It originates in  [C.E. Shannon, "A Mathematical Theory of Communication" *The Bell System Technical Journal,* Vol. 27, pp. 379–423, 623–656, July, October, 1948.](http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf)

Don't be turned off by the date; because it was written in a time when clear communication, instead of technical obscurantism, was valued in publications, the paper is quite readable.