# Shannon entropy as expected information content

Tags: entropy, information-theory

I'm struggling with a form of viewing Shannon Entropy. Cover & Thomas say that entropy is the expected value of information content. So there is a random variable $X$ with distribution $P(X)$ and its entropy would be given by $H(X) = \underset{x\in X}{\sum}p(x)\log_2\frac{1}{p(x)}$.

My problem is when calculating entropy of a series of outcomes of $X$. If these outcomes are $x_1, x_2\in X$, is it appropriate to calculate the entropy of this set as $H(x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{2}\log_2\frac{1}{p(x_1)} + \frac{1}{2}\log_2\frac{1}{p(x_2)}$? If this is not Shannon Entropy, then is it another known measurement? Also, how can I calculate the entropy of such set?

Comment: It is appropriate if and only if $p(x_1) = p(x_2) = 0.5$. If not, it's something else, namely the average of $\log_2 p_i$.

Comment: Thanks! $p(x_1)$ and $p(x_2)$ are not $0.5$. But $\log_2\frac{1}{p(x)}$ is the information content, and multiplying by $0.5$ would make for the expected value of information content in this case, would it not?

Edit: I also think it is not Shannon Entropy, but I'm struggling with the fact that within a set of occurrences probabilities will change, and how it affects entropy is still not very clear to me.

Comment: No, because differing probabilities enter the definition. If I work out the expected height of a population I don't just throw possible heights in and average them. I have to weight by their probabilities.

Comment: Related:  [Statistical interpretation of Maximum Entropy Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66186/statistical-interpretation-of-maximum-entropy-distribution/245198#245198)